# How can I add a date from string to a JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, date, jcombobox

Hi guys just trying to have on the JComboBox dates that are retrieved from a string...but also able to change on GUI if I want to...Im going crazy over this because I dunno how to do it...Cheers =)

```
public class StudentInfoGUI extends JPanel{  

private JTextField stFirstName;
private JTextField stLastName;
private JComboBox birthDate,birthMonth,birthYear;
private JRadioButton genderMale,genderFemale;
private JLabel l1,l2,l3,l4,l5;

public StudentInfoGUI(){


    super();
    StudentInfo st = new StudentInfo("123456","Homer","Simpsons","01011970",'m');

    l1 = new JLabel("First name:");
    stFirstName = new JTextField(st.getFirstName());
    l2 = new JLabel("Last name:");
    stLastName = new JTextField(st.getLastName());

    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
   // int date = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    //int month = cal.
    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    l3 = new JLabel("Birthday");
    birthDate = new JComboBox();
    birthDate.addItem(st.getBirthday());
    //birthMonth.addItem(month);
    birthYear = new JComboBox();


    l4 = new JLabel("male");
    genderMale = new JRadioButton();
    l5 = new JLabel("female");
    genderFemale = new JRadioButton();
    if(st.getGender()== 'm'){
        genderMale.setSelected(true);
    }
    else
        genderFemale.setSelected(true);


    JPanel stPanel = new JPanel();
    stPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,4));

    stPanel.add(l1);
    stPanel.add(stFirstName);
    stPanel.add(l2);
    stPanel.add(stLastName);
    stPanel.add(l3);
    stPanel.add(birthDate);
    stPanel.add(birthMonth);
    stPanel.add(birthYear);
    stPanel.add(l4);
    stPanel.add(genderMale);
    stPanel.add(l5);
    stPanel.add(genderFemale);

    add(stPanel);
} 
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Student info");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new StudentInfoGUI());
    frame.pack(); 
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: `"just trying to have on the JComboBox dates that are retrieved from a string...but also able to change on GUI if I want to..."` -- please translate this into English.

Comment: U saying that u don't understand my question ?sghhh

I need to have a date(dd/mm/yyyy) on jcombobox that comes from a string...I can get it with method st.getBirthday()...

and also be able to change on the panel if needed

is it clear?
dunno how to explain any better :P
thanks

Comment: I'm quite don't understand too, and be sure that this community to must to has a long time to get used to my new offshoot of English

Comment: A question about a `JComboBox` and `Date`s, and the first things I see in this code snippet are "First Name" and "Last Name" labels and text fields. How about posting only relevant code. That at least shows some effort on your part

Comment: your comment is ridiculous robin...
I thought having the entire code there(which is not that big)
would make easier for others to understand the program...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [How to Use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) & most specifically the [`JSpinner.DateEditor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSpinner.DateEditor.html).

[image: Spinner date demo.]

Comment: better than bothering with ..., I'm always forgot for JSpinner

Comment: @mKorbel It does tend to get forgotten.  :(  ..except when I happen by.  :)  Thought your answer was excellent..

Comment: basic stuff and quick Renderer (made in power safe mode) to has an issue with selection :-), please psssssssssst

Answer (score 3):

- read Oracle tutorial [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html)
- use methods implemented in [JComboBox APIs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html)
- lets `XxxRenderer` works to uncomment `//comboBoxDate.setRenderer(new ComboBoxRenderer());`

then

[image]

from code, based only on standard methods implemented in API

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.ListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class ComboBoxModels {

    private JComboBox comboBoxDouble;
    private JComboBox comboBoxInteger;
    private JComboBox comboBoxBoolean;
    private JComboBox comboBoxIcon;
    private JComboBox comboBoxDate;
    private Vector<Double> doubleVector = new Vector<Double>();
    private Vector<Integer> integerVector = new Vector<Integer>();
    private Vector<Boolean> booleanVector = new Vector<Boolean>();
    private Vector<Icon> iconVector = new Vector<Icon>();
    private Vector<Date> dateVector = new Vector<Date>();
    private Icon icon1 = ((UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon")));
    private Icon icon2 = (UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon"));
    private Icon icon3 = (UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.warningIcon"));
    private Icon icon4 = (UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.questionIcon"));
    private SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");

    public ComboBoxModels() {
        doubleVector.addElement(1.001);
        doubleVector.addElement(10.00);
        doubleVector.addElement(0.95);
        doubleVector.addElement(4.2);
        comboBoxDouble = new JComboBox(doubleVector);
        integerVector.addElement(1);
        integerVector.addElement(2);
        integerVector.addElement(3);
        integerVector.addElement(4);
        comboBoxInteger = new JComboBox(integerVector);
        booleanVector.add(Boolean.TRUE);
        booleanVector.add(Boolean.FALSE);
        comboBoxBoolean = new JComboBox(booleanVector);
        iconVector.addElement(icon1);
        iconVector.addElement(icon2);
        iconVector.addElement(icon3);
        iconVector.addElement(icon4);
        comboBoxIcon = new JComboBox(iconVector);
        dateVector.addElement(parseDate("25.01.2013"));
        dateVector.addElement(parseDate("01.02.2013"));
        dateVector.addElement(parseDate("03.03.2013"));
        dateVector.addElement(parseDate("18.04.2013"));
        comboBoxDate = new JComboBox(dateVector);
        //comboBoxDate.setRenderer(new ComboBoxRenderer());
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2, 5, 5));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(comboBoxDouble);
        frame.add(comboBoxInteger);
        frame.add(comboBoxBoolean);
        frame.add(comboBoxIcon);
        frame.add(comboBoxDate);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private Date parseDate(String str) {
        Date date = new Date();
        try {
            date = sdf.parse(str);
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
        }
        return date;
    }

    private class ComboBoxRenderer extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


        public ComboBoxRenderer() {
            setOpaque(true);
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1));
        }

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
                int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            if (!(value instanceof Date)) {
                return this;
            }
            setText(sdf.format((Date) value));
            return this;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ComboBoxModels comboBoxModel = new ComboBoxModels();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use some really good libraries for that purpose like JCalendar. Here you can find some information: [JCalendar](http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/)

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 2):

You can convert a `String` to a `Date` using [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) if you know the format...

```
String strDate = "01011970";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy").parse(strDate);
```

To change the Date, you need to supply the `Date`s that valid for the user to select.

I'd suggest Swinglabs' [`JXDatePicker`](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t45447.html) or has already been suggested, `JCalendar` and save yourself a lot of pain

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SimpleDateFormat`

```
String edate = "November 1, 1970";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(edate);
System.out.println(date);
```

Output

```
Sun Nov 01 00:00:00 IST 1970
```